# How to embed ArcMap graph into winforms dialog using .NET/C# and ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, add-in, graph

I am creating an addin for ArcMap in csharp and want to add a graph to a dialog.

The native arcgis graph control doesn't seem to been available from the visual studio toolbox.

I can't figure out how to do this from code.

How can i do this?

Comment: Why do you want an ArcGis graph? Wouldn't it be better to create a windows forms graph using data from ArcGis objects accessing data?

Comment: Arcgis graph provides some more features, that my users want, like highlighting selected features and they can be added to map-layout (i am considering just using winforms graph's, if this is not possible and just adding a button to launch the graph manager if they want a arcgis graph)

Comment: It's fairly easy to select features in the data frame and highlight see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792888/how-to-select-feature-and-highlight-in-arcgis-using-c-sharp. To add to the map look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644288/converting-a-windows-chart-form-to-a-picture which makes the chart into a static image.

Comment: Adding static images is easy (with both arcgis or winforms graph's), but my customers prefer a more dynamic integrated approach -> none your links shows how to select on the map and highlight them on graph.

Comment: So you want a tool that will select/unselect using mouse clicks and then graph an attribute... is that correct? Is the graph to be on the layout or on the windows form?

Comment: Yes, with graph on the windows form (with a add to layout button or a save as image button), but that's the easy part, interaction between map and graph that is the hard part and the esri graph-control has that out of the box.

Comment: How far into creating the tool are you? Have you created the add-in tool and form? Have you implemented OnMouseDown for selecting features?

Comment: It will be new extra function on an existing addin, but right now i just doing research on how to approach this.